# Error when trying to initialize a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

C beginner here. I'm trying to create a function that returns a new instance of struct that I defined in my header file. I do this in the `List_create` function. When I try to compile my code I get the following error message.

> error: initializing 'ListNode' (aka 'struct ListNode') with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

I call the `List_create` function in my `test.c` file. Any help is appreciated, I have trouble grasping basic concepts of C but I'm trying to learn.

#### dll.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode;

typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List {
    int count;
    ListNode *first;
    ListNode *last;
} List;

List *List_create();

void add_to_back(List *list, void *value);
void *remove_from_back(List *list);

void add_to_front(List *list, void *value);
void *remove_from_front(List *list);

void *remove_from_list(List *list, ListNode *node);
```

#### dll.c

```
#include <dll.h>

List *List_create()
{
    return calloc(1, sizeof(List));
}

void add_to_back(List *list, void *value)
{  
    ListNode node = *calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
    node->value = value;

    if (list->first == NULL) {
        list->first = node;
        list->last = node;
    } else {
        list->last->next = node;
        node->prev = list->last;
        list->last = node;
    }
}

void *remove_from_back(List *list)
{
    return 0;  
}

void add_to_front(List *list, void *value)
{
}

void *remove_from_front(List *list)
{
    return 0;
}

 *remove_from_list(List *list, ListNode *node)
{
    return 0;
}
```

#### test.c

```
 #include <dll.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int test_add_to_back() {
    List *list = List_create();

    int new_value = 1;
    add_to_back(list, &new_value);
    ListNode *curr = list->first;
    if (curr->value != &new_value) return 0;
    if (list->first->value != list->last->value || list->last->value != new_value) return 0;

    add_to_back(list, 2);   
    add_to_back(list, 3);   
    add_to_back(list, 4);   
    curr = list->first;

    if (list->last->value != 4) return 0;
    //if (curr-> (void) *value != 1) return 0;
    //curr = curr->next;
    //if (curr->(void) *value != 2) return 0;
    //curr = curr->next;
    //if (curr-> (void) *value != 3) return 0;
    //curr = curr->next;
    //if (curr->(void) *value != 4) return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    printf("helloworld\n");
    if(test_add_to_back() != 1) printf("Add to back test failed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The declaration of `struct ListNode;` is useless. And using non-prototype-style function declarators is an [obsolescent feature](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6) by the standard.

Comment: Can you expand on why its useless. Also what do you mean non-prototype-style function declarators?

Comment: I'm very confident I did provide a link to the standard which explains it. And the declaration is useless, because you have it instantly following once more. Try removing it and see.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. But why would the function declarator be obsolete? Is there another way to put the function in my header?

Comment: @DanielKobe in C, declaring a function with empty `()` means that the function may take any number of arguments, instead you should use `(void)` to indicate zero arguments.

Comment: @DanielKobe: I did not write the declarator is obsolete. Just read the linked part of the C standard, it is very clear: "The use of function declarators **with empty parentheses** (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature." (emphasise mine). You might want to do more research in the standard about what that in particular means. (Hint: `f(void)`)

Comment: @RyanHaining: It is a bit more complicated: What you wrote is true for a declaration only. For a definition it very well means there are no arguments. This is an asymmetry, which is likely the reason for omitting this. The C++ way is locked for legacy reasons.

Comment: Also, it's not "very clear". It's confusing if you're new to C.

Comment: @Olaf that's why I said *declaring* and not *defining*. what do you mean by "locked"?

Comment: As a side note, it's also true for function pointers: `int (*fp)()` can point to anything that returns int. This can actually be useful from time to time.

Comment: @RyanHaining: Sorry, that should have been "**b**locked". You just cannot do this because of the whole bunch of legacy code (and the commitee having backwards compatibility as the holy grail) which is the reason this is asymmetric. I wrote about a **declarator**, not _declaration_ in my initial comment. A definition is also a declaration (and includes a declarator), thus the linked parapgraph applies to both.

Comment: @Olaf idk what you're getting at with backwards compatibility, in C++ `void f();` and `void f(void);` are equivalent.

Comment: ,@RyanHaining: Either I cannot make clear what I mean or - well ... Anyway, I give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `calloc` is `void*`. Hence, `*calloc(...)` is of type `void`.

```
ListNode node = *calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
```

is equivalent to:

```
ListNode node = (void)(<<some vale>>);
```

That's what the compiler is complaining about. You cannot assign `void` to a `ListNode`. What you need is:

```
ListNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
```

Comment: Thanks. Why then can you assign `void*` to `ListNode`?

Comment: You can't. You can assign a `void*` to a `ListNode*`.

Comment: I see, but why not the other way around then  `void` to a `ListNode`?

Comment: @DanielKobe, that needs a long answer, too long to fit in a comment. There are probably other SO questions that address that.

Comment: `void` is a type meaning _no value_. It has no value. `void*` is a pointer to nothing in particular... but it's still a pointer and still has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
ListNode node = * calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
```

to

```
ListNode *node = (ListNode*) calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
```

Remember that doing

```
void *value;
```

would require you to do suitable typecasting if wish to do something useful
with it. In fact `void*` is used for versatility.

Comment: Why should be CALLOC cast'ed to ListNode*?

Comment: @Michi :Just corrected it. I overlooked the left side and missed the fact that node is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

calloc can return (void *) pointer, you should change to:

> List *List_create()
>   {
>      return (List *)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
>   }
>   some compiler require you to do suitable type.